# postgresql/postgis division by zero error

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a query where I am calculating acreage of two intersecting tables and what percentage that new acreage is compared to the old acreage.here is the error

```
ERROR:  division by zero
********** Error **********

ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

query

```
select p.objectid,acreage old_acreage,p.shape,sum(st_area(st_intersection(p.shape,lulc.shape))/43560) as new_acreage,
    sum(st_area(st_intersection(p.shape,lulc.shape))/43560)/acreage as agr_use_percentage

from base_layers.modiv_parcels_2015 p join base_layers.lulc_huc_hl_clip lulc on st_intersects(p.shape,lulc.shape) 

where lu12 in(2100,2200,2300,2400,2140,2150) group by p.objectid,acreage,p.shape
```

what can be done to circumvent this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to guard against dividing by zero, as the exception suggests. You are dividing by the field `acreage`, so if that is ever 0 then the query will fail. Add this to your `where` clause:

```
AND acreage > 0
```

Comment: okay great that worked..very strange it threw this error here when I have been using that parcel layer for many other calculations..

Answer (score 3):

Another option to avoid the 'Div by 0' errors would be to wrap the expression with a case statement.

```
select 
    p.objectid,
    acreage old_acreage,
    p.shape,
    sum(st_area(st_intersection(p.shape,lulc.shape))/43560) as new_acreage,
    case 
        when acreage = 0 then -1 -- some value to indicate div by 0 result
        else sum(st_area(st_intersection(p.shape,lulc.shape))/43560)/acreage
    end as agr_use_percentage

from base_layers.modiv_parcels_2015 p 
    join base_layers.lulc_huc_hl_clip lulc on st_intersects(p.shape,lulc.shape) 

where lu12 in(2100,2200,2300,2400,2140,2150) group by p.objectid,acreage,p.shape;
```